# change the values through radio buttons doesn't invoke the method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a html with two radio button.

```
 <div data-toggle="buttons">
                   <label class="btn active">
                   <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="ongoing" ng-change="update(value)">Ongoing
                   </label>                               
                   <label class="btn">
                   <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="completed" ng-change="update(value)">Past 
                   </label>
             </div>
```

When I toggle the radio buttons the method in js file is not getting called.

JS

```
$scope.update = function(value){
console.log("the click value is"+value)     
}
```

Comment: You code is working perfectly here is fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/x6ed222u/

Comment: Try giving a different model for each of those radio buttons

Comment: check any error showed in console.

Comment: no error is shown but still for me its not working properly ..

Comment: @Karthik replicate it with plunker or fiddle :-P
We will check it.

Comment: and @Karthik, tell to us what navigator you are using.